# Could not load credentials from any providers

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cli

I'm using docker on the AWS ec2 instance to setup a project and having this error while intializing `s3` in code (locally it works fine problem is with docker image):

```
Error [CredentialsError]: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:895:34)
     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:387:35)
     at IncomingMessage.emit (domain.js:470:12)
     at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
   statusCode: 404,
   retryable: false,
   time: 2021-07-13T14:02:47.898Z,
   code: 'CredentialsError',
   originalError: {
     message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
     statusCode: 404,
     retryable: false,
     time: 2021-07-13T14:02:47.898Z,
     code: 'CredentialsError',
     originalError: {
       message: 'EC2 Metadata roleName request returned error',
       statusCode: 404,
       retryable: false,
       time: 2021-07-13T14:02:47.897Z
     }
   }
 }
```

I have already added the credentials and config file into `~/.aws/` dir. From the error if I set the `AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1` it gives this error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/.aws/credentials'
     at Object.openSync (fs.js:498:3)
     at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:394:35)
     at Object.readFileSync (/project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:95:26)
     at IniLoader.parseFile (/project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/shared-ini/ini-loader.js:6:47)
     at IniLoader.loadFrom (/project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/shared-ini/ini-loader.js:56:30)
     at Config.region (/project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/node_loader.js:100:36)
     at Config.set (/project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:514:39)
     at Config.<anonymous> (/project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:349:12)
     at Config.each (/project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:507:32)
     at new Config (/project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:348:19) {
   errno: -2,
   syscall: 'open',
   code: 'ENOENT',
   path: '/root/.aws/credentials'
}
```

Adding `aws.config.update()` inspired from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56152697/could-not-load-credentials-from-any-providers-when-attempting-upload-to-aws-s3#answers) giving this error:

```
<rejected> TypeError: Cannot read property 'accessKeyId' of undefined
      at Config.extractCredentials (/project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:576:17)
      at Config.update (/project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:452:20)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/project/dist/helpers/s3.js:10:12)
      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/project/dist/helpers/s3v2.js:14:21)
      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
```

Comment: It seems that you have .aws file in a user's home directory, but you are running the app as root.

Comment: yes, perhaps. so, what should I do?

Comment: Well one thing you can do is add the .aws to root's home. But you probably want to avoid running stuff as root